# time series plot with x axis in "year"-"month" in R

Tags: r

I have a "monthly data" I want to plot the data such that I get a date in the format `%Y-%m" (2001-01)` on the x-axis.  Say my data is `pcp <- rnorm(24)`.

I have tried:

```
PCP <- ts(pcp, frequency = 12, start = 2001)
plot(PCP)
```

but the plot only has years on the x-axis.

How do I get a plot with the date format I desire on the x-axis?

Comment: I retracted my vote to close but please put in some work to make the question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  What's `pcp`?

Comment: The question is not answered by my previous one, it is totally different question here I'm asking about the plot, how to do it such that the x-axis includes the months not only years

Comment: @MarwahSoliman a good question would have been reproducible. You should have had something like `pcp <- norm(24)` above your code, so that folks could execute `PCP` and `plot(PCP)`.  This would have avoided the downvotes. Finally, you ought to pick an answer and select the tick to accept it -- you get status for this yourself, and as your status builds folks will give your questions more care.

Comment: Well I'm new to this website so I'm sorry if I didn't select the tick, I didn't know what is it for , so thank you for pointing out that

Comment: @MarwahSoliman I edited your question to give you an idea of what a good question looks like.

Comment: I have a question I'm trying to plot a map for Greater Toronto, I have plotted the Canada map but can't plot certain county, any help

Comment: I have used :                                                     map('county', 'Ontario', interior=TRUE)
map.scale()
map.axes() but it doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find that the excellent `xts` package is the best way to store your data. If you've not got it, you can download with `install.packages('xts')`.

Let's start from basics -- including making `pcp`, as you've not supplied it.

```
require(xts)
pcp <- rnorm(24)
PCP <- ts(pcp, frequency = 12, start = 2001)
plot(as.xts(PCP), major.format = "%Y-%m")
```

This gives you a chart something like the following.  You can tweak the dates by altering the string passed to `major.format`. For example, `"%b-%y"` yields dates in the `Jan-01` format for Jan 2001.

[image: example plot]

Comment: Also note that the [xtsExtra package on R-Forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118) has some improved plotting for xts objects.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an idea with toy data since the question is not reproducible. Hopefully it helps

```
R> foo = ts(rnorm(36), frequency = 12, start = 2001)
R> plot(foo, xaxt = "n")
R> tsp = attributes(foo)$tsp
R> dates = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), by = "month", along = foo)
R> axis(1, at = seq(tsp[1], tsp[2], along = foo), labels = format(dates, "%Y-%m"))
```

[image: Output]

ggplot version with data that looks like yours

```
R> df = data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2001-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 36), pcp = rnorm(36))
R> library(ggplot2)
R> library(scales)
R> p = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = pcp)) + geom_line()
R> p + scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"), breaks = date_breaks("months")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use `axis.POSIXct {graphics}`
Here the example from the help of this function:

```
with(beaver1, {
time <- strptime(paste(1990, day, time %/% 100, time %% 100),
                 "%Y %j %H %M")
plot(time, temp, type = "l") # axis at 4-hour intervals.
# now label every hour on the time axis
plot(time, temp, type = "l", xaxt = "n")
r <- as.POSIXct(round(range(time), "hours"))
axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(r[1], r[2], by = "hour"), format = "%H")
})
```

in your case change the format to `format="%Y-%m"`

Regards,