# How to represent two columns of year and day as a date?

Tags: r, date, text-files

I have a text file consisting of 3 columns as shown below. the measurements are taken each day for several years (2001-2013). I want to plot a time series for `valu1` but as the year and day are separated I have a problem:

to read the file:

```
  LR=read.table("C:\\Users\\dat.txt", sep ='', header =TRUE)
```

header:

```
 head(LR)
     Year day  valu1 
   1 2001   1         0     
   2 2001   2         1     
   3 2001   3         2    
   4 2001   4         0       
   5 2001   5        0.30     
   6 2001   6         0
```

I tried this:

```
    LR$Year=as.Date(as.character(LR$Year))
    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Year", value = numeric(0)) : 
    replacement has 0 rows, data has .
```

I do not know if all days are available so I wonder if we can tell **R** that if a date is missing, just replace it with NA but still consider the missing date in the plot with no value in the plot.

Comment: `LR$date` does not exist in `LR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
LR$date <- as.Date(paste(LR$Year, LR$day, sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%j")
```

I assumed here that `day` is the day of the year, so something that goes from 1 - 366. This is the `%j` in the format.

Comment: Missing dates are just not plotted. If you are plotting a line it will interpolate between your observations, if you are plotting points you will just have a gap where you have missing observations.

Comment: `LR$value1` has the same length as `LR$Year` and `LR$day`. If the resulting  `LR$date` is `NA`, this point will not appear on the plot.

Comment: If you do `plot(LR$date, LR$value1)` the x-axis is dates because you use `as.Date` to create the column.

Comment: You can check the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758006/time-series-plot-with-x-axis-in-year-month-in-r) question