# Timeseries plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am plotting a time series data in R. In the X-axis I should get the year as 2014, 2015, 2016 where as I'm getting 2014.0, 2014.5, 2015.0, 2015.5, 2016.0 and 2016.5 which is very annoying. How can I get rid of this?

Below given is the code I have used.

```
inflow<-ts(inflow,start = c(2014,1),frequency = 12)
plot(inflow, xlab="Year", ylab="Inflow Count")
```

Can anyone please help me how should I get rid of the decimal part in the year field in X-axis. I am attaching the image ([R Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnCUF.png)) with my resulting output as well.

Comment: Those are in the format YYYY.M you might want to manually change the x-axis labels or use some of the alternate functions here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758006/time-series-plot-with-x-axis-in-year-month-in-r

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the input data or the way you want to plot your data. Give following lines a try for your needs:

```
data(USAccDeaths) 
USAccDeaths
plot(USAccDeaths, type="l", pch=16, cex=1, col="#425a10",bty="l", xlab="Year",ylab="Accident Deaths", main="Accident Deaths USA 1973 - 1979")
```

The input data:

```
YEAR   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
1973  9007  8106  8928  9137 10017 10826 11317 10744  9713  9938  9161  8927
1974  7750  6981  8038  8422  8714  9512 10120  9823  8743  9129  8710  8680
1975  8162  7306  8124  7870  9387  9556 10093  9620  8285  8466  8160  8034
1976  7717  7461  7767  7925  8623  8945 10078  9179  8037  8488  7874  8647
1977  7792  6957  7726  8106  8890  9299 10625  9302  8314  8850  8265  8796
1978  7836  6892  7791  8192  9115  9434 10484  9827  9110  9070  8633  9240
```

and the resulting plot:

[image]