# Created time series not matched

Tags: r, time-series

There is a list of numbers and I want to make it a time series, and plot it.

```
month_data <- c(34,28,32,26,28,29,39,33,31,31,34,29)

month_ts <- ts(month_data, start = c(2017, 01), frequency = 12)

plot(month_ts)
```

The plot starts from zero, and it doesn't show the values accordingly, for example the peak (39) July is sits in May.

What went wrong? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It is plotting the points at each of `2017 + (0:11/12)` not neatly 2017.0/1/2 etc. Take a peak here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758006/time-series-plot-with-x-axis-in-year-month-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thelatemail already said it. You can see it when you extract the time from the ts-object:

```
> time(month_ts)
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct
2017 2017.000 2017.083 2017.167 2017.250 2017.333 2017.417 2017.500 2017.583 2017.667 2017.750
          Nov      Dec
2017 2017.833 2017.917
```

This doesn't matter if your time scale is big and you have a lot of data. In your case however it doesn't work.

There are other ways to plot a ts-object:

```
library(ggfortify)

autoplot(month_ts)
```

[image]